# Trying to install Mjml

Tags: node.js, npm, mjml

I am trying to install Mjml email marketing framework on my MAC but I keep receiving this error below

enter code here

```
MacBook-Air:// desina$ npm init -y && npm install mjml
npm ERR! path /package.json
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/package.json'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/package.json']
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, open \'/package.json\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: '/package.json' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/desina/.
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you're not an administrator on your computer hence the permission-related errors. Ask an administrator to grant you permissions.

An alternative is to run the commands with `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have node js installed and do you have admin privileges for installing? I found the easier method for working in MJML is to install the app, as it comes with the app and language pre-installed.